# how to get the cookies of two servers 1. runs application (HTTP) , 2. runs websocket(WS) server?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

I have an application which is hosted on a **tomcat server** on port **8080**. and the same application using **websocket** connection which is pointing to another **tomcat server** on port **1234**. But when i executing "**document.cookie**" from web browser console it showing the cookies from websocket server(2nd server. port 1234) only, but i need **all cookies from both servers**.
can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way around this as that's the way cookies were designed - one server can't see another's cookies.

The easiest way for you to do this would be to add some proxy code into the Tomcat server that forwards all requests sent to a certain endpoint to your server on port 1234.

For example, if you want all requests going to http://localhost:8080/websockets to be forwarded to your server at http://localhost:1234 then configure Tomcat running on port 8080 like this:

```
ProxyPass         /websockets  http://localhost:1234/webapp
ProxyPassReverse  /websockets  http://localhost:1234/webapp
```

Here are the docs for Tomcat proxy, they're a good start but are fairly basic:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

In production you'll probably have a dedicated proxy server in front of both (like Apache HTTP or NGINX) and that will also solve your cookie issue given that the browser will only be sending requests to a single server/port.